# pouchdb db.put (update doc) - response include docs

Tags: pouchdb

Is it possible to get a document in response from:

```
db.put(doc, [docId], [docRev], [options], [callback])
```

instead of a plain confirmation with ok, _id, and _rev:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "id": "mydoc",
  "rev": "1-A6157A5EA545C99B00FF904EEF05FD9F"
}
```

to use _include_docs:true and get something like this:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "id": "mydoc",
  "rev": "1-A6157A5EA545C99B00FF904EEF05FD9F",
  "doc":{ updated document goes here ?? }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. However, you can just inspect the very document you just `put()` into the database. ;)

Comment: thx @nlawson, it could be cool if there will be an option to return back the whole updated doc in the future.